# Ios BT Connectivity & Raspberry Pi

Tags: ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a idea that requires connecting an ios device to a Raspberry Pi without the end user having to do anything special. The device will not be connected to an existing wifi network so BT or wifi hotspot seem to be my only options, BT preferred.

I'm aware that Apple does require some sort of BT hardware approval which I wont have I'll be using generic BT hardware. Once a connection is established I then want to be able to request data or call API's running on the Raspberry PI.

Does any of this sound achievable and are there any links that may help.

Comment: This question is not about an issue with code, and therefore doesn't fit on StackOverflow. A question like this is more at home on SuperUser. Please flag your question so a moderator can migrate it, or delete it and move it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two flavours of Bluetooth: the so-called **Bluetooth Classic**, and the newer **Bluetooth Low Energy** (also called Smart Bluetooth or Bluetooth 4.0, though this is actually incorrect as BT 4.0 includes both Classic and Low Energy).

On iOS, Bluetooth Classic devices do indeed need to go through specific processes (MFi), or use an existing BT protocol supported by iOS to be used.

However, you can connect to any Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device, without any need for MFi, approval, or support by iOS. This is done though the [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1) framework.

As long as Bluetooth is enable in the iDevice, you can connect to a BLE device without any user interaction (though UX usually dictates doing so, so a user can actually select a specific device if there are many "matching" devices in range).